# frequency counter with Lattice ice40 dev board

Tags: frequency, fpga, lattice

Hello I am very new to the FPGAs.
My goal is to make a frequency counter that would be able to count 5-6Mhz with +-5Hz error.

Would Lattice ICE40 be sufficient for this task?

This board looks pretty simple to start and not so expensive.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about a logic level signal (i.e., no ADC required), you can sample ICE40 pins (LVCMOS33) at up to 250MHz, while 40MHz would have been enough to get about 2-4 samples, and if the input signal is relatively stable, it is sufficient to infer the frequency with a good accuracy.